# PN circuit, playing with doped wafers

Tags: circuit-analysis, semiconductors, pn-junction

So I have two silicon wafers. One is P type (doped with boron) and one is N type (doped with phosphorus). I am just playing around with these and thought to myself, "can I make a diode if I sandwich these two wafers together?" So I made a simple circuit with a 120 ohm resistor, an LED , the two wafers, and a 9VDC. My thought is that the P-type is my anode and the n-type is by cathode. With this belief I built the following circuit expecting the LED to light up.

circuit 1:

- (9VDC source) -> 120 ohm -> P type (boron) -> N type (phosphorus)  -> LED - (9VDC return)
  Result: I could not see the LED light up at all (not even faintly).

This had me stumped. So I flipped the order of my wafers to make this circuit:

circuit 2:

- (9VDC source) -> 120 ohm -> N type (phosphorus) -> P type (boron) -> LED - (9VDC return)
  Result: I can dimly see the LED light up. When I hold the two wafers together firmly I can see it light up better.

I tried both these experiments multiple times with similar results. This looks to me like I broke physics. Shouldn't circuit 1 light up and circuit 2 not light up at all?
Is having the LED in the circuit somehow messing things up?

Note: The wafers are different sizes so I am sure I did not mix them up.

UPDATE:

After looking into the comments, I reassessed how I was 'sandwiching' the wafers together. Both wafers are polished on one side. I took the unpolished sides (the rougher sides) and placed these so that they were touching. I then held the circuit wires firmly in place. These are my new, and expected results:

circuit:

- (9VDC source) -> 120 ohm -> P type (boron) -> N type (phosphorus)  -> LED - (9VDC return)
  Result: Very bright!

circuit:

- (9VDC source) -> 120 ohm -> N type (phosphorus) -> P type (boron) -> LED - (9VDC return)
  Result: Dimly lit!

The answer to my problem was a simple google of 'ohmic and rectifying contacts'.

Thank you.

Comment: You're probably getting stronger rectification at the silicon-metal junctions than at the junction between the two wafers. It takes a great deal of care to make an "ohmic" (non-rectifying) connection between metal and silicon.

Comment: @DaveTweed, thank you. You were right. I flipped the wafers around so that the unpolished sides were touching. I now have my expected results (see post updates).